# Google Pay - Request Failed

Tags: android, android-pay, google-pay

We are using Google Pay in our app with latest `play-services-wallet:19.0.1`.
On some devices we are getting this error after calling `AutoResolveHelper.resolveTask(Task, Activity, int)`:

[image: google pay error]

Couldn't find any related logs.
Any idea what might be wrong?